# Third-party services integration with Jira through REST API

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin

I’m trying to integrate a third-party tool with Jira server via REST API.
Currently we have a customized Jira used by our client with a business specific issue types.
Basically all I need is to be able to create an issue of a given type, get response (success/error) and get metadata (list of required and optional fields) for that tool via REST API.

We have a create issue page on WebUI, where user can submit his request.
But the problem is all validation logic is “smashed” between some Javascript code, Behaviours and SIL Programs Manager add-ons, AJS scripts, Jira native fields configuration etc. 
So I can’t use “plain” Jira REST API directly because it creates issues without taking in account business rules of a given issue type - e.g. requires fields, one fields can have values depending on another field’s value, an attachment is a required as part of an issue etc.

My question is what is the best way to make an integration with Jira.
I want to be sure if someone will try to create an issue via REST API, the data is consistent according to the issue business rules.
I was thinking to write some "proxy" REST API, which will do the all validation needed and create (or edit) / reject the request.
We've developed a separate Jira plugin which serves some scenarios. So, I can add those API to the plugin.

Or, use Jira REST API endpoints like POST /issue (and PUT /issue/), and I have to define a new screen for it, set all required fields via standard Jira settings, set Cascading fields rules and the standard validator will check if everything is ok out-of-the box?
Sorry, I’m new to Jira and not sure if my current understanding is correct now.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. Best to validate the data in a single place (with one set of code) before calling the create REST API. That way you can also modify the validation logic more easily over time. I think I would probably define a new REST endpoint. ScriptRunner lets you script that nowadays